# Make Notion Database (table) public to query via API

Tags: notion-api

We have long used Notion as the "source of record" which is then reflected into a database for analytics and other processing.  We use simple private integrations assigned to our Notion Tables as "connections" to facilitate secure API access, which works well.

Being a database vendor, I'd now like to create and share a public demo project on how we load data from Notion into our platform, without (obviously) exposing our actual keys or data.

So, I created a small [demo Notion table](https://spaceandtimedb.notion.site/be1d2120a16445d89e0bf9105a4c3881), made the table public, and created a new integration to keep it isolated from the rest of our environment - this setup is the "source" of the data load.  However, I'm not sure how to make the demo Notion table publicly available via API.  Ideally, the new Integration could be made "public", aka just allow anyone to query via API (they can already see the public page via web).  I started down the integration "distribution" workflow to make the integration public, however that ended with a required OAuth, which is not what I'm looking for.  I don't want to auth anyone, I just want to allow everyone.

I also tried simply calling the API on the "public" demo Notion table without the integration, but it threw a 404... as if the connection was not setup - which it wasn't, so no surprise there.  I'm assuming I need some "public" connection, but I don't see how to getterdun.

Is this possible to do?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to be REALLY explicit...  Success is being able to use with ANY API Key and the standard Query API (https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query) to return all records (2 today) from this DB object:  be1d2120a16445d89e0bf9105a4c3881